# Always show pagination controls for Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

Is there a way to make Kaminari always show pagination controls even when total page count is 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend Kaminari at run-time, a process known as [monkey-patching]. Just create a file in config/initializers/kaminari_ext.rb with the following:

```
module Kaminari
  module Helpers
    class Paginator
      def render(&block)
        instance_eval(&block) if @options[:total_pages] >= 1
        @output_buffer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You will need to restart your rails server for the changes to take effect.

If you get an error about **num_pages** being nil you can change **num_pages** within a theme, changing it to **total_pages**. Eventually **num_pages** will be deprecated in lieu of **total_pages**.

For example, I had to change **_page.html.haml**:

```
= raw("PAGE  #{page}  OF  #{total_pages}")
```